# "От ошибок не гарантирован"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

В данном случае *не гарантирован = не застрахован.*

Скажите, пожалуйста, это устаревшее употребление или сейчас тоже вполне в силе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словарь трудностей русского языка (Ю. А. Бельчиков, О. И. Ражева, 2015) допускает оба варианта управления в зависимости от значения глагола:

> **Гарантировать** *(кому) что* - в значении «обеспечить»:
>   гарантировать гражданам соблюдение прав; гарантировать больным хороший
>   уход, гарантировать сохранность банковских вкладов; гарантировать
>   покупателю качество.
>
> **Гарантировать** *(кого) от чего* – в значении «защитить»:
>   гарантировать путешественников от несчастных случаев; гарантировать от
>   последствий стихийных бедствий. Ср. также: никто не гарантирован от
>   стихийных бедствий.

https://difficulties.academic.ru/38/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Можно представить себе и буквальное эквивалентное выражение: не гарантирован - не обеспечен гарантией (свыше) от чего-то. На мой взгляд, можно трактовать это выражение и как более формальное по отношению к "не застрахован".

Comment: То есть это значение не уходит из языка?

Comment: Я слышу такое время от времени.

Comment: Спасибо! Кстати, а не может это быть более формальным вариантом, чем "застрахован"?

Comment: Да, я воспринимаю это как более формальное выражение.

Comment: Проголосовал за ответ, но, если можно, не могли бы Вы включить в него ту мысль, что это более формальное выражение? В итоге это оказалось самым важным для меня в этом вопросе.